# Unable to read data from the transport connection.System.Net.Sockets.SocketException from compact framework?

Tags: web-services, wcf, windows-ce

We get this error about 2 weeks and working resolve but still can't solved !

Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Error Detail;

```
    System.Net.WebException: Unable to read data from the transport connection.System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown error (0x0).
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.fillBuffer(HttpWebRequest request, Connection connection, CoreResponseData data)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.getLine(HttpWebRequest request, Connection connection, CoreResponseData data)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.parseResponse(HttpWebRequest request, Connection connection, Boolean defaultKeepAlive)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.startReceiving(Connection connection)
   at System.Net.Connection.startReceiving(Object ignored)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.finishGetResponse()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters, WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Check these urls, may be useful to you  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970549   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/11/19/why-net-compact-framework-fails-to-call-some-https-web-servers.aspx

Comment: Check this as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2008/01/03/fixing-exception-messages-on-the-net-compact-framework-3-5.aspx